# How to delete lines from file in C#

Tags: c#

I have come up with following code to delete some portions of the file. Parameters to method are filePath and List of locations along with length to delete from each location.

Can you please check I am doing it correct? Thanks

NOTE: Parts to be deletes will not overlap. SO I have not added check for it.

```
    static void DeleteFileParts(string filePath, List<Tuple<int, int>> T)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            int tLen = 0;
            int lastWriteL = 0;
            int len = (int)fileStream.Length;
            byte[] b1 = new byte[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < T.Count; i++)
            {
                Tuple<int, int> t = T[i];
                tLen += t.Item2;

                fileStream.Seek(t.Item1 + t.Item2, 0);

                int b1Len = i == T.Count - 1 ? (len - t.Item1 - t.Item2) : (T[i + 1].Item1 - t.Item1 - t.Item2);
                fileStream.Read(b1, 0, b1Len);

                fileStream.Seek(lastWriteL == 0 ? t.Item1 : lastWriteL, 0);
                fileStream.Write(b1, 0, b1Len);

                lastWriteL += t.Item1 + b1Len;
            }

            fileStream.SetLength(len - tLen);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is working code, it would probably be more appropriate for CodeReview SE

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Read` method wrong (but you are not alone, that's quite common).

The `Read` method doesn't guarantee that it will read as many bytes as you request. It may read only part of that, and it will return the number of bytes that it actually put in the buffer. You need to use that return value, and keep reading until you have all the bytes that you need:

```
int len = 0;
while (len < b1Len) {
  len += fileStream.Read(b1, len, b1Len - len);
}
```